# PHP disable error from specific file?

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am getting hundreds of from ANSI.php. Here is an example:

```
/usr/share/pear/File/ANSI.php on line 553 Notice: Undefined offset: 75 in 
/usr/share/pear/File/ANSI.php on line 555 Notice: Undefined offset: 76 in 
/usr/share/pear/File/ANSI.php on line 553 Notice: Undefined offset: 76 in 
/usr/share/pear/File/ANSI.php on line 555 Notice: Undefined offset: 77 in
/usr/share/pear/File/ANSI.php on line 555 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
/usr/share/pear/File/ANSI.php on line 496 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
```

This is generating from:

```
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
```

Everything is working. I suspect the old machines I am working with are giving ANSI.php a hard time.

Is there a way i can disable just the error messages from ANSI.PHP and keep the others? Unless someone has a way of fixing the error.

Comment: I don't know ansi lib but can you make sure that `$ssh->read()` is a string? like `$ansi->appendString((string)$ssh->read());`

Comment: So I swapped in $ansi->appendString((string)$ssh->read()); Same results.

Comment: What about `$str = $ssh->read(); if (!empty($str)) { $ansi->appendString($str); }`

Comment: $Str would always have a value because i dont have a clear() and the connection is established. so there is always something there to read. I did what you suggested just to be sure and it had the same results. The filter is a great idea, I think we just need a to filter out illegal chars perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplest Solution (Sub-Optimal)**

I guess the simplest way to suppress the errors would be to use the error suppression operator `@`. eg.

```
@$ansi->appendString($str);
```

**Optimal Solution (Possibly)**

There have been two commits to phpseclib since the latest release (1.0.7 and 2.0.6, as of this post) that fixed issues with File/ANSI.php:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/5c792f6bc1fa8a5d26b43fb8200191c073637e15
https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/84d1628cb7734134b1ba80545b38985025942b79

More info:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1161
https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1150

Kinda makes me wonder if one of those might fix the issue for you.

**Fallback to Optimal Solution**

If the previously mentioned "optimal solution" doesn't fix the issue for you then it would be nice to fix the problem at the source. What'd help me do that would be a copy of the data you got before you passed it to `$ansi->appendString()`. To make it so the characters don't get garbled because they're extended ASCII maybe hex encode it. eg. `echo bin2hex($ssh->read());` or something.

Comment: It sounds like this is a known issue that may be released in the next stable. I can wait for that and the @$ansi should be fine until then. unfortunately a lot of data is confidential and I can only post ambiguous or redacted sections otherwise I would give you the HEX.